# How does cache works when accessing multiple memory locations in a loop?

Tags: caching, memory, optimization

I am currently studying data oriented design / Entity-Component-System and considering applying it to some algorithms, if not a whole program.

At a low level I understand how this kind of design allows for writing code that uses efficient memory access through caching.

I have seen tons of examples like this one :

```
// position is a (x,y) coordinate pair

for ( int i=0; i!=position_count; ++i ) {
  do_something_with(position[i]);
}
```

I get that. Instead of iterating through all "fat" objects (with a x,y,state,name,hp,etc...), we iterate through a smaller portion of that object (here a single position x,y). 
These positions are contained into a contiguous memory location (an array). The code seems efficient: data is minimal and everything is read in a single loop, allowing L1 cache to do its job.

Now in theory this seems perfect, but in a real world example I am wondering how it works.

In this example:

```
// visual is a (x,y) coordinate pair
// and also contain an index to the sprite array

for ( int i=0; i!=visual_count; ++i ) {
      sprite s = sprites[visual[i].sprite_id];
      s.draw_at( visual[i].x, visual[i].y );
}
```

Here we are using the read data to do something useful.
But this results in reading a second memory location (sprite).

Sprite is likely to contain more data that a single pair of coordinate (a width, an height, a texture location etc..).
Also, the sprite array is likely to be quite random access.

Doesn't it "ruin" the previous caching of iterating through positions ?
What goes into L1, L2, L3 cache ?
What is the best approach to writing efficient code in this context ?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is "it depends".  And to some extent you shouldnt put too much effort into pre-optimizing, sure there are situations where you really need/want to and you then need to target specific systems that you are optimizing for understanding it may affect performance negatively on other systems.

The L1 in theory is the nearest and fastest ram, most expensive and smallest in size.  The algorithm/logic used to determine how accesses are stored in L1 is really the question here.  It is possible knowing how that works (which you might have to do experimentally if you dont have information on how the logic works) to setup your memory address spaces such that multiple items be it in the same array or in different arrays do not collide in the cache.  It is very possible, esp if you choose aligned address spaces that are far apart (many/most of the low address bits match and only high address bits differ) that they will hit the same space in the cache and leave other parts unused.

you also need to know if the cache operates on virtual or physical addresses.  often the lower bits of the virtual and physical match anyway, but that can still be the address bits used by the cache.

L2 contains L1 plus more stuff. And L3 holds all the L2 stuff plus some more.  Whenever L1 misses it then fetches through L2 then it either hits l2 (is already there) or misses L2 and then reads through L3 where it either hits or misses, making whatever is in L1 is in L2 and L3 and whatever in L2 is in L3.

Comment: if your loop is large enough it is quite possible that the loop data itself is larger than the L1 size and colliding and evicting itself, but hopefully all fitting in L2.  not as near and as fast as L1 but still faster than what is on the other side of L2 (if you even have an L2).